# Clutch pedal won't go to the floor to engage neutral safety switch

Tags: clutch, truck, gmc, sierra

This is a 1993 K1500 Sierra 4x4.

I just replaced the clutch master and slave cylinders and bled the line.

The clutch has pressure but it won't go all the way down to engage the neutral safety switch.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! There's no adjustment you can make to the NSS itself? Is it based off the pedal, or the transmission (assuming pedal, but thought I'd ask)? Are you sure the rod is completely engaged into the master cylinder? No adjustment to the rod at the pedal? Are you *positive* you got the correct master cylinder?